# ORGANIZE / DISTRIBTE BY with CREATE TABLE in MPP systems

Tags: parallel-processing, teradata, netezza, azure-synapse

How is CREATE TABLE statement's performance influenced by ORGANIZE BY / DISTRIBUTE BY clause in MPP systems (Netezza / Teradata / Synapse)?
Also, what key should be picked for distribution in such MPP system?

Comment: Should be the same for all MPP system: Bad column(s) to distribute data will result in a skewed distribution/processing. And the rules for choosing these column(s) are the same as for any partitioning schema: should be used based on equality (maybe between) in most of the queries to get *partition elimination*.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that as long as you choose a ‘distribution’ that enables a very even spread of rows across nodes, then it has little to no effect on insert performance.

On Netezza the ‘organize’ is not enforced while you create the table, not even while you insert/update data. The Groom operation does that on your request later. Side note: When doing CTAS or large inserts you should ‘order by’ in the insert statement if possible.

About choosing ‘distribution’ columns:

1. always ensure a very even spread (if not possible: RANDOM is better)
2. and never use more than one column
3. and choose one you plan to do a lot of ‘equal join’ on (a LOT)

About choosing ‘organization’ columns

1. only consider columns you plan to do a lot of ‘simple where’ clauses against (=,<,>, LIKE)
2. tend towards those with few distinct values
3. and ‘time’ columns are always a good guess

Hint: sometimes you get a ‘free’ organize effect on a column because it is closely related to another column that you already organize on.
Example: If the create_date on average is less than 30 days away from the end_date in a table with 5 years of data, then you will have that effect